# RSS feeds in new twitter

Tags: twitter, rss

Does anyone know where to find the RSS feeds in the new twitter? I cannot find the rss icon and the source of the page just points to "Your Twitter Favorites" even though I am on the page of the user I want to get an RSS feed from...

Simple I know, but its bugging me to no end!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***2014 edit:***

It looks like Twitter has retired RSS feeds, and now only exports data as JSON:

> **[What output formats will API v1.1 support?](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#10648)**
>
> API v1.1 will support JSON only. We’ve been hinting at this for some
>   time now, first dropping XML support on the Streaming API and more
>   recently on the trends API. XML, Atom, and RSS are infrequently used
>   today, and we’ve chosen to throw our support behind the JSON format
>   shared across the platform. Consequently, we’ve decided to discontinue
>   support for these other formats. For historical context, when we
>   originally built the API all major languages did not have performant,
>   well vetted libraries supporting JSON - today they do.

---

***Orignal 2010 answer:***

Here are the various feed URLs (using the account "Twitter" for these examples):
http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.rss
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/Twitter.rss
http://twitter.com/favorites/Twitter.rss
http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=Twitter

The new Twitter layout isn't very RSS-friendly, unfortunately.

Comment: So how did you get these addresses? I simply cannot find anything on this in the new twitter

Comment: At first I was looking at the favorites RSS URL and wondered if the others were similar based on how to call them from the API. So looked at the Twitter dev docs and found them by trial and error. After that, though, I also managed to leave the New Twitter preview and went back to ye olde Twitter layout, and that had these RSS feeds in clear sight.

Comment: None of the URLs work anymore. Likely API changed in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to find it because Twitter stopped support for RSS :(

Something I needed, so built a Twitter to RSS converter, it works on hashtags, searches and lists. I've now opened it up totally free for anyone else who needs a solution.

Get it here - [Twitter RSS Feed Generator](https://publicate.it/twitter-rss-feed-generator/)

Comment: Your answer is a completely valid answer to this question but it does seem to be self promotion. You might want to take a look at [how not to be a spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You can make your question even better by demonstrating how your product works.

Answer (score 0):

Recommende you to use the free website ahejlsberg, put the id into the textbox next to `@`, then click the "Fetch RSS" button.
[image: capture]
You can get the RSS feed url: https://twitrss.me/twitter_user_to_rss/?user=ahejlsberg.

Answer (score -2):

I found that this works for particular users (I had been trying to figure out their ids which was the way rss used to work but this works fine):

[Updated]
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=johnpiper

[Updated Sept 2014]
no longer works again...

**[Alternative Solution: May 2015]**

I have since discovered http://www.queryfeed.net

```
http://www.queryfeed.net/twitter?q=from%3Ajohnpiper
```

See the home page for further documentation about how to structure other queries. The service does not seem to return all tweets.