# Twitter RSS Feed

Tags: url, twitter, rss

I'm trying to find the rss feed on twitter of for example, my user. Before, it was just on the url bar where I click and I can get the url for the rss feed. After doing some searching, it seems like Twitter has removed the functionality. [Twitter RSS](http://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/111-features/articles/15361-how-to-find-your-rss-feed)

Do you guys know another way to get the rss url?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.quora.com/Twitter-1/Is-Twitter-planning-to-kill-off-RSS-feed-access-to-user-streams

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RSS feeds in new twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189965/rss-feeds-in-new-twitter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per

https://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/111-features/articles/15361-how-to-find-your-rss-feed

> Twitter recently stopped supporting
>   basic authentication over RSS in favor
>   of OAuth, an authentication method
>   that lets you use applications without
>   giving them your password. You can
>   read more about the change here:
>   http://blog.twitter.com/2010/08/twitter-applications-and-oauth.html
>
> Because of this change, we no longer
>   directly support RSS feeds on Twitter.
>
> If you would like to continue using
>   RSS feeds from Twitter accounts, we
>   recommend using a 3rd-party service.
>   Or, if you are comfortable with
>   coding, use our developer resources to
>   retrieve statuses. The following link
>   provides information about how to use
>   OAuth to retrieve statuses:
>   http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/home_timeline
>   Please note that you will first need
>   to sign up for a Twitter application
>   if you would like to use the method
>   linked above. You can sign up for an
>   app here:
>   http://dev.twitter.com/apps/new

but I assume you've already seen this? are you looking for a third party service?

Comment: Don't worry mate. Found a way. [How to find your twitter rss feed.](http://www.glenwoodfin.com/rss/how-to-find-your-twitter-rss-feed-in-2011/)